# Bokeh: tools='reset' makes the graph fixed

Tags: python, python-3.x, plot, bokeh

I wanted to put only reset toolbar on by the graph, so I was trying to like

```
logo=None, tools='reset'
```

The reset button is actually placed but instead the graph is fixed and cannot move from original position.

How can I improve it?

Comment: Hi welcome to Stack Overflow.. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve... Also provide a full error traceback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To move the plot you just need to add the [**PanTool**](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/tools.html#pantool). Check this minimal example:

```py
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.io import curdoc

plot = figure(
    width=300,
    height=300,
    tools='pan,reset',
    logo=None,
)

x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y = [4, 3, 2, 1]

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x, y=y))

plot.circle(
    x='x',
    y='y',
    source=source,
    size=5,
    fill_alpha=1.0,
    fill_color='green',
    line_color=None,
)

curdoc().add_root(plot)
```

Run this with `bokeh serve --show example.py`